# Adding edge to nodes with same names, different attributes in NetworkX

Tags: python, graph, networkx

In NetworkX I have a multiple nodes that represent logic gates, so for example I have multiple AND nodes. The difference between them is in attributes:

```
G.add_node('AND', name='xyz')
G.add_node('AND', name='qwe')
```

I want to draw an edge to the **specific** AND node, for example with a name 'xyz'. 
How do I do that?

I tried:

```
for node, attr in graph.nodes(data=True):
  if attr.get('xor_name') == xor_name:
     graph.add_edge(n1, node)
```

However I end up with having only one AND node, not multiple ones.

Answer (score -1):

You have added the node `AND` multiple times, each time with the attribute `name`.  Each time you overwrote the previous value of the attribute `name` with the new value.

Check it:

```
G.add_node('AND', name='xyz')
G.add_node('AND', name='qwe')
G.nodes(data=True) #data=True means it prints the attributes
> [('AND', {'name': 'qwe'})]
```

You are intending for `AND` to be an attribute of the node `xyz`, not `xyz` to be an attribute of the node `AND`.  So try that:

```
G.add_node('xyz', nodetype = 'AND')
G.nodes(data=True)
> [('AND', {'name': 'qwe'}), ('xyz', {'nodetype': 'AND'})]
```

Comment: Thank you! If I tried this solution, how do I make an edge to the node with specific attributes?

Comment: @izotop were you able to figure out how to make an edge to the node w/ specific attribute?